# I was trying to use conda env create command in amazon linux 2, it is taking forever at "Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): \"

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, anaconda, miniconda

i had tried to run conda env create -f  using miniconda and anaconda3 on an EC2 instance using Amazon linux 2, still it is taking forever at **Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ** , can anyone help me where i was going wrong, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: python tag removed. The question relates to amazon-EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of space (AFAIK), my EC2 instance was full of images and containers, after removing few unnecessary ones, I was able to create the environment